# When running version 20.04.3 LTS via /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic I get a black screen

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Today I updated my Ubuntu 20.04.2 to version 20.04.3 and got a black screen, under which I hear the sound of volume up sliders. My EFI partition is banned in the disk management application. Later, I did a clean install of Ubuntu and again I was left on a black screen, under which I hear the sound of Ubuntu starting. Now I can run version 20.04.3 only in recovery mode. And this is sad, because I used three axes on my device, which I started using rEFInd. Now I have only two axes left, and without Ubuntu I feel sad.

I don't want to allow Ubuntu access to the EFI partition and most likely suffer because of this.

And I would like to know if this is a bug or a principle of future Ubuntu releases ?

Maybe I need to fix something in the file "/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic" ?
But there is so much written there that if I figure it out, I risk becoming a developer myself. I wouldn't want to burden myself with a mess of high-level codes. Because I think it's not a rewarding job, it's like building sand castles... and there are specially trained people for this.

My work related to programming has been trolled for decades and I don't do it anymore, which is very happy. Now I am a simple user who listens to music, watches videos, goes fishing and hunting... I walk barefoot on the grass and I'm happy about it.

Ubuntu does not work, and this is sad but not critical.
But the fact that you are not doing your job well is a fact.

Comment: join the club. search the site for the term "black screen" or similar. Ubuntu did just add the new secureboot compatible chainloading boot loader. Just as a test, try enabling secureboot and see if you get different results. If it works, it will make A LOT of users here happy. Or if it is enabled, try disabling. could be either. If you figure it out, let me know please.

Comment: Well, before I had no problems with the installation and most likely it's not about how I install Ubuntu. Most likely, the question is how Ubuntu is obsessively trying to occupy my EFI partition, and how Ubuntu monitors the screen parameters. In recovery mode, Ubuntu starts without problems.

Comment: Ubuntu stopped start with rEFInd, which has the ability to use Touch Input. The key is used to start it: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-XX-generic = black screen = :(

Comment: I don't want to carry a keyboard all the time to run any axis on my tablet. These are simple things. With the help of rEFInd, I select axis with my finger on the screen.

Comment: Nate T, I checked what you wanted, turned on secureboot and successfully booted Ubuntu. No problem. But that didn't solve my problem. I can only see the Ubuntu desktop in two cases... ; When I select "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" during installation and "Additionally/Kernel-5.11.0-27 (recovery mode)/ resume normal boot" .

Comment: Secureboot doesnt stop ubuntu (or any OS) from booting in any case. It will let it boot, but it restricts it. This manifests itself as missing features or a broken install. Usually, it restricts features like internet access, or any access at all, but I could see it manifesting as something like this as well. At any rate, it was just sort of a Hail Mary attempt. As I said, there are a lot of users in your situation. There are two (three) tools that I can think of, that will help you here. Ill add an answer so I can provide more detail.

Comment: This is not Ubuntu. We aren't employees, and if we are paid, someone else must be cashing my checks. This is a social media sight made up mostly of random people who (I assume) enjoy helping others with Ubuntu as a hobby and learning a lot in the process. Your last paragraph is like, after seeing that a Facebook update was glitchy, you decided to tell all of your Facebook friends that they weren't doing their jobs... By the way, thank you for trying the SecureBoot thing. At least now you can mark it off the list of potential culprits. That is an important part of the process.